# Calculate angle of reach for projectile given velocity and distance

Tags: javascript, calculus

I've been trying to implement projectile motion in Javascript and I'm stuck at figuring out the angle (from which to derive the x and y velocity)

```
var v = 1;
var d = 10;
var g = -1;
var angle = 0.5 * Math.asin((g*d)/(v*v));
```

I would've expected someting like this to work, since it's coming from here [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion#Angle_of_reach).
The values I seem to get are either NaN or a very small number.

To give a bit more context; The projectile has to go from point A to point B (the distance is `d` in my code) where A and B are at the same height. Later on I would like to randomize the distance and angle a bit, but I assume that's not going to be an issue once this angle problem is solved.

EDIT:
As for a better example:

```
var v = 100;
var d = 100;
var g = 1;  // I've made this positive now
var angle = 0.5 * Math.asin((g*d)/(v*v));
```

This says that angle is now 0.005

Answer (score 0):

Im not really good at this physics problrm but i'll try

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/asin

- the arg for Math.asin() should be between -1 and 1. Otherwise it returns NaN
- from your example you run `Math.asin(-10/1)` maybe the velocity has max distance that it could cover. No matter the angle, 1m/s wont reach 500m distance for example
- in your link there is a formula to count the max distance from given velocity and angle. Use that to confirm your variables are relevant.
- angles are represented in values between -1 to 1 in cos, sin, tan. It makes sense that NaN (or values outside the range) means no angle can cover the distance

Hope it helps a bit

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to see if I can incorporate some of those bulletpoints in my code to get a better understanding of what's happening

Answer (score 0):

Note from the same wikipedia page you linked `d_max = v*v/g`. Given your inputs this evaluates to 1. Therefore a distance of 10 is impossible.

Another way to notice this is the range of sin is (-1,1). Therefore asin of any number outside of this range is undefined. `(g*d)/(v*v)` is 10, so `Math.asin` returns NaN